# pdf-tools: customize highlight color

Tags: customize, highlighting, pdf-tools

How can I customize pdf-tools' default color for highlighting (from yellow to something else)?

Comment: Only one question per post, please. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have in my `init` file; modify as appropriate:

```
(setq pdf-annot-default-annotation-properties
   '((t
      (label . "Pablo"))
     (text
      (color . "#ff0000")
      (icon . "Note"))
     (highlight
      (color . "LightBlue2"))
     (underline
      (color . "blue"))
     (squiggly
      (color . "orange"))
     (strike-out
      (color . "red"))))
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for